# Spring MVC UTF-8 encoding Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, utf-8, character-encoding

I am facing a weird problem with charset encoding in my spring mvc application.
When i submit Persian characters and print that on Spring Controller it prints ?????? (marks) 
For each jsp, I am using i have explicitly set the charset and pageEncoding to UTF-8.

Is this a framework issue with Spring 3.1.4.

Filter code in my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

code from my jps,

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

**Is there any mistake in my configuration ?**

Comment: if your using `tomcat`, change the `server.xml` file propery called `URIEncoding =UTF-8`

Comment: Do you use maven? If yes you sould set in properties section

<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

Comment: Could you apply utf-8 encoding at filter level ?

Comment: @ArvindKatte Yes i applied `URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"` in server.xml

Also i tried apply Custom Filter as well but same result.